# In BigQuery, how can I find the S2_ID at level 16 corresponding to each (latitude, longitude)?

Tags: google-bigquery, geolocation, gis, s2

I am working with the Chicago-taxi-trips dataset and I want to find the average fare per pick up location S2_ID at level 16 for the given date, based on the pickup
time of the trip

[S2_ID](http://s2geometry.io/resources/s2cell_statistics)

[Chicago-taxi-trips dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/chicago/chicago-taxi-trips-bq)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

There is now a native BigQuery function,

`S2_CELLIDFROMPOINT(point_geography[, level => cell_level])`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#s2_cellidfrompoint

---

Carto provides a set of UDF functions for geospatial projects, including working with S2. See their introduction here:
https://carto.com/blog/spatial-functions-bigquery-uber/

The UDFs are available in a public `jslibs` project. To compute S2 cellid from a point use code like

```
SELECT jslibs.s2.ST_S2(
           ST_GeogPoint(<longitude>, <latitude>),
           <cell_level>);
```

Note that you might need to replace `s2` dataset with a regional version, depending on where you want to run the queries.

That said, it would be great if you could describe the use case for S2 cells in BigQuery? BigQuery team is interested in how these are used and might consider adding native S2 functionality in the future.

Comment: I'd like to have BQ support something like this Azure function - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/geo-polygon-to-s2cells-function()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/geo-polygon-to-s2cells-function) - I have a use case where I want to get the cell IDs of a s2 grid (level 12) that overlap with a circle of radius X km centered at a location.

Is there an easy way to do that currently in BQ? `jslibs` don't seem to support this (happy to be proven wrong here)

Comment: Exactly. Also getting error when using carto-os (previously jslibs) in BQ. Currently, achieving the same functionality required me to write some JS UDF (have to do certain modifications in s2geometry.js from carto-os) and use it in BQ.

Comment: There is now such a function, S2_COVERINGCELLIDS https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#s2_coveringcellids

Comment: not in release notes yet?

Comment: @MichaelEntin awesome!!!